# cx_Oracle for Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle

I know that python 3.6 is only available since a few days. What do you think when cx_Oracle for python 3.6 will become available?

I'm not a python expert. May I also ask why there is a dependency between the python minor version and the Oracle library?

thanks a lot, and have a great new year.

Juergen

Answer (score 3):

The reason there is a dependency is because cx_Oracle is a C extension, which means that it must be compiled every time the Python C API changes. That generally happens each time a minor version is released. As to when cx_Oracle will be released for Python 3.6 -- that is unknown but hopefully will be soon! In the meantime you can compile it for yourself and use it before any official release is made.

Comment: The 5.3 release has just been made.